# How do I extract n,e key from RSA256 public key in perl?

Tags: perl, cryptography, rsa

I use this Python code

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.importKey( open('public.key').read() )
```

But I have no idea how to extract **n** and **e** keys in Perl.

Please explain about **n** and **e** extraction.

Comment: What did you find when you searched for a solution yourself?

Comment: *"Please explain about **n** and **e** extraction"* What do you mean here? The public and private keys each consist of two values. They have the same *modulus*—**n**—and different *exponents*—**e** and **d** respectively. This isn't the place to explain more in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You would want

```
my $key = Crypt::RSA::Key::Public->new( Filename => 'public.key' );
```